# innerHtml not working in ie for table

Tags: javascript

I have a table, and in that table i want to add few rows by javascript, but this is not working in ie10.

```
<table id="itemidentitynamedeploy">
</table>
```

javascript Code

```
var itemidentitynamedeploy = document.getElementById('itemidentitynamedeploy');
for(var x=0;x<6;x++)
{
itemidentitynamedeploy.innerHTML += "<tr><td>"+x+"</td></tr>";
}
```

Please Suggest.

Comment: Can you show us the value of `userIdsDeployed`?

Comment: may be you are having problem with `userIdsDeployed` variable, Try it with static values it's working fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kssnq/1/)

Comment: Use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`

Comment: define "not working". Any JavaScript error?

Comment: value of itemidentitynamedeploy.innerHTML shows 1</td></tr>

Comment: @AbhinavParashar check this out http://jsfiddle.net/89jWX/

Comment: Open the Developer Tools in IE (press F12) and check that the Browser Mode is actually IE10, and you're not running as an earlier version of IE. Table contents were readonly in every prior version (they finally fixed it in IE10) so you couldn't set a new value for the `innerHTML` property.

Answer (score 1):

There's wrong order of `tr` and `td` enclosing tags (`</tr></td>`). Use this

```
itemidentitynamedeploy.innerHTML += "<tr><td>"+x+"</td></tr>";
```

instead of this

```
itemidentitynamedeploy.innerHTML += "<tr><td>"+x+"</tr></td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try..

```
 var tr=itemidentitynamedeploy.insertRow(x);
 var td=tr.insertCell(0);
 td.innerHTML=x
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working fiddle (tested in IE10 and Chrome),

http://jsfiddle.net/HjMwJ/

Since the above works with the JavaScript called onload, if you are not getting this working in IE10 in your code, maybe you need to make sure that the JavaScript in your solution is being called once the DOM element is loaded too...

If you're not sure how to do this, you could do it by any of the following options

- Wrapping your javascript in a `$(function() { ... })` if you're using jQuery
- Putting the `<script>` tag containing this JavaScript at the end of your `<body>`
- Making sure your code fires once the window has loaded... `window.onload=function(){ ... };`

each of these methods has different subtle lifecycle/timing implications which are described elsewhere on this forum.